# Can a graphql mutation be wired inside a DataFetcher class along with query?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

**Error:FieldUndefined: Field 'createUser' in type 'Query' is undefined @ 'createUser'"**

```
@Service
public class GraphQlService {

    @Value("classpath:schema.graphql")
    Resource resource;

    private GraphQL graphQL;


    @Autowired
    UserDataFetcher userFetcher;
    @Autowired
    PostDataFetcher postFetcher;


    @PostConstruct
    public void loadSchema() throws IOException {

        File schemaFile = resource.getFile();
        TypeDefinitionRegistry typeRegistry = new SchemaParser().parse(schemaFile);
        RuntimeWiring wiring = buildRuntimeWiring();
        GraphQLSchema schema = new SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, wiring);
        graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build();


    }

    private RuntimeWiring buildRuntimeWiring() {
        return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type("Query", typeWiring -> typeWiring
                        .dataFetcher("user", userFetcher)
                        .dataFetcher("post", postFetcher))
                .type("Mutation", typeWiring -> typeWiring
                        .dataFetcher("createUser", userFetcher))
                .build();
    }

    public GraphQL getGraphQL() {
        return graphQL;
    }

}
```

**1. Cant I use common datafetcher/reslover for both Query and Mutation
    as I have done below in a single class.It is not able to find
    createUser?**

```
@Component
public class UserDataFetcher implements DataFetcher<List<User>> {
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

public User createUser(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
    String username = environment.getArgument("username");
    String location= environment.getArgument("location");
    User[] follower = environment.getArgument("followers");
    User[] following = environment.getArgument("following");
    Post[] pos = environment.getArgument("posts");

    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setFollowers(follower);
    user.setFollowing(following);
    user.setLocation(location);
    user.setPosts(pos);
    return userRepository.save(user);
}


@Override
public List<User> get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

//SDL below for schema

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}

type User{
    id:ID!
    username:String!
    followers:[User]
    following:[User]
    location:String!
    posts:[Posts]
}

type Post{
    id: ID
    title: String!
    author: User!

}



type Query{
    user: [User]
    post: [Post]
}

type Mutation{
    createUser(username: String!, location: String!,followers: [User],following:[User],posts:[Post]):User

}
```

**2. Is the schema correct because it would say User and Post are not mentioned as InputType. I tried InputType for User and Post but
    couldnt get it working.How should correct schema for storing
    followers and following look like ?**

Answer (score 0):

1) No, each `DataFetcher` implementation can do a single operation only - that's the `get` method the interface specifies. How would the framework know to call the `createUser` method?

2) No, the schema is not valid. You can not use `User` as an argument (input) type. You need to define a separate input type, e.g.

```
input UserInput {
   username:String!
   followers:[ID!]
   following:[ID!]
   location:String!
}
```

Just think, if you could make `User` the input, how would you provide the mandatory ID? What if `User` implements an interface, since interfaces are not defined for inputs? Imagine if `User` had a recursive field type. In output, that would be fine (as you control the nesting level directly), but would be impossible to satisfy for an input type.

The rules for inputs and output are quite different, so the types need to be defined separately.

Also, in this example, only the `ID`s are optionally expected for the followers or the followed, instead of the full objects, as it often makes more sense.